# Trying to save username / password in cookie ; JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, cookies

I saw this example about storing login information in cookie.

http://eisabainyo.net/weblog/2009/02/20/store-login-information-in-cookie-using-jquery/

Tried it, but can't seem to get it to work. I have to plugin and I don't see what's wrong here.

This page is Login.aspx which points to AccountMenu.aspx

**EDIT** IT'S FOR A DEMO, TEST, WHATEVER YOU WANNA CALL IT. this site will never go online. I KNOW this is not the way to do it. I'm looking for help to solve my problem, not people telling me this is bad design.

(...)

```
    <div data-role="content">

    <form action="AccountMenu.aspx" method="post" id="login">

        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input type="text" id="email" name="email"/>

        <label for="password"><%= GetLabel("password") %></label>
        <input id="password" type="password" name="password" />

        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
            <input type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember" class="custom" checked="true" />
            <label for="remember">Remember me ?</label>
        </fieldset>
        </div>

        <input type="hidden" name="submit" value="submitted" />
        <button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" data-theme="a"  value="<%= GetLabel("new-login") %>" ></button>
        <button type="button" disabled="disabled" data-theme="a" value="<%= GetLabel("new-account") %>"></button>        

    </div>

 </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        if ($('#remember').attr('checked')) 
        {
            var email = $('#email').attr("value");
            var password = $('#password').attr("value");

            // set cookies to expire in 14 days
            $.cookie('email', email, { expires: 14 });
            $.cookie('password', password, { expires: 14 });
            $.cookie('remember', true, { expires: 14 });                
        }
        else
        {
            // reset cookies
            $.cookie('email', null);
            $.cookie('password', null);
            $.cookie('remember', null);
        }

        var remember = $.cookie('remember');
        if (remember == 'true') 
        {
            var email = $.cookie('email');
            var password = $.cookie('password');
            // autofill the fields
            $('#email').attr("value", email);
            $('#password').attr("value", password);
        }

    </script>
```

Comment: don't store a username or password in a cookie ever. Don't do it. End of story.

Comment: I won't use your site if you store my password like that in a cookie!!!

Comment: What you could do is store a session id in a cookie. That is acceptable...just make sure the session expires!

Comment: My $0.02. I wouldn't do that.

Comment: Oh boy should I have said that in my post. IT'S FOR A DEMO, TEST, WHATEVER YOU WANNA CALL IT. this site will never go online. I KNOW this is not the way to do it. I'm looking for help to solve my problem, not people telling me this is bad design.

Comment: What problem are you having?  You say "doesn't work", but what exactly doesn't work.  Are you seeing any javascript errors in the error console?  Have you done any debugging to see whether the values are being retrieved from the cookie?  You have to do some detective work yourself and report the results to us before we can help you.

Comment: I'm not sure of Stackoverflow's stance on this, but I would rather this not be here as others will come here and possibly think this is acceptable.

Comment: Do you use master page for this one? You'll not find the element in html since asp.net generates the client id differently from the one you've defined.

Comment: Well, thanks a lot (insert sarcasm here) to everyone who downvoted for no reason. I'll figure it out on my own. For those who tried to help, thank you.

Comment: @JFFF: This is **our duty** to tell you that this is not the *right* way to do if you intended to put this in production. You had to tell this at the begining of your post (as your edit did) to try to get some answers.

Comment: To try to solve your case, you may have to wrap your code within a `submit` event because right here, everything you have in your code will get executed onload (and *only* onload), I don't think that's what you intend to do (but maybe you should tell us what doesn't work and so on as jfriend00 pointed out in his comment).

Comment: -1 for storing username & password in a cookie

Comment: @JFFF Please see my example. I agree on the overzealousness here. I had to ask the same question THREE times to not have it closed

Comment: I echo the comment from @PrisonerZERO ... username and password in a cookie is bad jojo.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

you need to actually call the code when the user fills in the form

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        var remember = $.cookie('remember');
        if (remember == 'true') 
        {
            var email = $.cookie('email');
            var password = $.cookie('password');
            // autofill the fields
            $('#email').val(email);
            $('#password').val(password);
        }


    $("#login").submit(function() {
        if ($('#remember').is(':checked')) {
            var email = $('#email').val();
            var password = $('#password').val();

            // set cookies to expire in 14 days
            $.cookie('email', email, { expires: 14 });
            $.cookie('password', password, { expires: 14 });
            $.cookie('remember', true, { expires: 14 });                
        }
        else
        {
            // reset cookies
            $.cookie('email', null);
            $.cookie('password', null);
            $.cookie('remember', null);
        }
  });
});
```

Comment: Simple and powerful

Comment: Hello! Is that safe to save password in a cookie without any encrypt?

Comment: It's better to store an encrypted token, but if another site than the one setting them can read your cookies you are already in trouble. SENDING the plaintext password is however a bad idea

Comment: Email and password should only be saved if they are correct. How can I find out (programmatically) if the userlogin was succhessful?

Comment: @drupalfan This is 10 year old code. You need to Ajax to the server to test the userid and password

Comment: I do not know in JavaScript if username and password are correct.
Is it possible to find out if the login was successful (not submitted with wrong login data) and if how?

Comment: Maybe it is easier to solve this in php after successful login and set the cookie then in php. Is it?

Comment: I want to avoid saving wrong username and password!

Comment: Please ask a new question with example of what you have done so far

Comment: I did it like this: I set the cookie in PHP (after successfull submtion of the loginform) and I reed the cookies and autofill the fields in jQuery. This works fine!

Answer (score 5):

```
document.cookie = "login=" + username_from_DOM_here + "-----" + password_from_DOM_here + "; secure";
```

Do not use a path in the cookie declaration and ensure that the page is HTTPS then you should be just fine.  Secure cookies can only be transmitted on HTTPS pages and ignoring the path qualifier ensures the cookie is not available to other parts of the site.  Also do not use an expires qualifier either, because the cookie will expire the moment the browser session ends.

There are some remaining security concerns in that the cookie still contains unhashed credentials in a text file.  Even though that cookie should never be transmitted outside of HTTPS it can still be accessed by malware outside the browser.

Answer (score 1):

```
**At first you need jquery.cookie.js file**

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

    var remember = $.cookie('remember');
    if (remember == 'true') 
    {
        var username = $.cookie('username');
        var password = $.cookie('password');
        // autofill the fields
        $('#username').val(username);
        $('#password').val(password);
    $('#login-check').attr('checked',true);//#login-check checkbox id..
    }


$("#UserLoginForm").submit(function() {
    if ($('#login-check').is(':checked')) {
        var username = $('#username').val();
        var password = $('#password').val();

        // set cookies to expire in 14 days
        $.cookie('username', username, { expires: 14 });
        $.cookie('password', password, { expires: 14 });
        $.cookie('remember', true, { expires: 14 });                
    }
    else
    {
        // reset cookies
        $.cookie('username', null);
        $.cookie('password', null);
        $.cookie('remember', null);
    }
  });
});

</script>
```